# Question on Classic Googles Site - How to Retrieve document links using GAS?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sites

This might be a long shot...but would anyone know if you can retrieve the google drive links that is added in a Classic Google Sites or where are photos/files uploaded directly to Sites stored?

For example, if one of the subpages contains several google drive files, can you retrieve the drive links using GAS?

I only found some information about images/photos where Google sites has its own image store, not sure if that is still accurate. Not so much as retrieving the file links added in a Google Sites.

Any information is greatly appreciated! TIA

Comment: Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask]

Comment: I have edited my question above. I tried tagging the google sites but I cannot find the correct tag name, sorry about that.